# How can I subtract one group from other groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
x <- read.csv(text="Group,X,Y
1,1,2
1,2,5
1,3,8
1,4,9
2,1,1
2,2,4
2,3,8
2,4,10
3,1,6
3,2,7
3,3,8
3,4,12")
```

My goal here is to take group 1, Y and subtract it with group1, Y, group 2, Y and group 3, Y. So the resulting dataframe looks like this

```
x <- read.csv(text="Group,X,Y,Z
1,1,2,0
1,2,5,0
1,3,8,0
1,4,9,0
2,1,1,-1
2,2,4,-1
2,3,8,0
2,4,10,1
3,1,6,4
3,2,7,2
3,3,8,0
3,4,12,3")
```

How can I achieve this? I did something along the lines of this:

````
        group_by(Group) %>%
        mutate(Z = dataset2[Group != 1]-dataset2[Group == 1])```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `group_by`, you can substract column `Y` with `Y[Group == 1]` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(Z = Y - Y[Group == 1])
#>    Group X  Y  Z
#> 1      1 1  2  0
#> 2      1 2  5  0
#> 3      1 3  8  0
#> 4      1 4  9  0
#> 5      2 1  1 -1
#> 6      2 2  4 -1
#> 7      2 3  8  0
#> 8      2 4 10  1
#> 9      3 1  6  4
#> 10     3 2  7  2
#> 11     3 3  8  0
#> 12     3 4 12  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just as a follow-up for a second case. If I want to subtract group 1 from group 2/group 3, but for group 1 I want to subtract every value by the first value in the group1 (in this case, 2)... How can I do that?